# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when switching from "Any CPU" to "x64" mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a project/solution that I can build fine in "`Any CPU`" mode using VS2015 SP2, but when I switch to "`x64`", VS2015 crashes and restarts, and I'm back to the "Any CPU" mode.

Here is a screencast: https://screenrecordings.tinytake.com/sf/NjY3NTE3XzMyMDU4ODM

It crashes right when I switch the drop down from "`Any CPU`" to "`x64`", not even executing any build action or alike.

I'm using `Visual Studio Professional 2015, Version 14.0.25123 Update 2` and 
`.NET Framework 4.6.01055` on `Windows 8.1`.

On another PC, the problem does not occur there with the same VS version and same project.

Coming from the Java world, I'm new to working with Visual Studio and .NET. Thanks for any hint where to look for a fix.

**Update**

When I check the Windows Event Logs under Application, I see to errors captured there:

(1)
Source: .NET Runtime

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00000000
```

(2) Source: Application Error

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25123.0, time stamp: 0x56f22f32
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18233, time stamp: 0x56bb4e1d
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e6054
Faulting process id: 0x2edc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1b199455bdb5d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 885c65a2-1d8c-11e6-8343-cc3d82aa16df
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Update 2**

Forum entry with dump created here, still awaiting feedback from Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2752690

Comment: You will have to spin the disable-addin/repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.  Only notable thing is that having more than one solution platform for managed code never makes much sense.  So delete it to get ahead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I had already tried to upgrade from SP1 to SP2 yesterday (the issue also occured in SP1), hoping that it would already fix it, but that did not do it yet. So I guess I need to reinstall it completely.

Comment: [try starting visual studio in safe mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms241278.aspx), sometimes that magically fixes problems like this.

Comment: capture a crash dump of VS (import this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmtkd1h7ans24v5/WER_VS_full.reg?dl=0 to configure WER to generate a dump: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx). After VS crashes, you can see a dmp in C:\localdumps, now import this reg to stop dmp creation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhj02wpza12bvwj/WER_VS_full_uninstall.reg?dl=0). Open the dmp in Windbg.exe (part of Windows SDK/Debugging Tools), setup symbols (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and run **!analyze -v**. Now look if you can see at which part VS crashes.

Comment: @Wurmloch Tried it but did not help.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Tried it but after the crash, I don't even have any C:\localdumps folder. Do I need to configure the registry manually after installing it? I.e. I see that Windows Error Reporting / WMR / Disable has value 1, and Windows Error Reporting / LocalDumps / Default has no value set. Is that correct? Anyhow, I checked the Windows Logs (see updated post), I will probably just go ahead in re-install the whole thing as Hans suggested.

Comment: ok, you disabled WER. Set the value to 0 to enable Error Reporting. the import can fail because of AV suites. Configure the value on your own. Follow the MSDN link. DumpType of 2

Comment: 0xc0000374 = STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION. Here you have to enable PageHeap. Run gflags.exe, to to image tab, type devenv.exe, press TAB and select the checkbox "enable pageheap". Now VS is slow, but crashes at the point were something gets corrupted.

Comment: were you able to get a crash dump?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I found wer-reports under C:\Users\mlin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive, a lot already since some months, just not under C:\localdumps (where would that path come from)? I set LocalDumps/DumpType=2 for full report. The latest error file I got now is: http://pastebin.com/p6E1FDHd - but not sure if this is the dump you mean. Screenshot of my registry now: https://snag.gy/gIm7hJ.jpg

Comment: @magicandre1981 I just found the above wer-reports because the registry pointed to that location: https://snag.gy/gya20k.jpg. Update: I also now found the real dumps by reading the registry documentation for property LocalDumps\DumpFolder: "The directory path. The default value is %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps." They were actually under this default path. Now I actually got dump files named link devenv.exe.31456.dmp :) Now I just need to analyze them...

Comment: Dump file opened in Windbg.exe: http://pastebin.com/FrTsgjrz

Comment: you need to fix the symbols (follow the KB link) and now run **!analyze -v**. Also open the dmp in a 32Bit/x86 Windbg not the 64bit Windbg

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the analysis: http://pastebin.com/fbDwQe3a By the way, I also entirely re-installed VS2015 as well as IIS Express, it does not help. The problem still exists.

Comment: you need to activate PageHeap for devenv.exe to see more. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543094(v=vs.85).aspx , http://magic.force.com/PublicKnowledge/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka2D00000000P3n&feoid=00ND0000005rAjf&refid=0EMD0000000EGc5 Type devenv.exe in the image filed and press TAB

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry, page heap now enabled (`devenv.exe: page heap enabled with flags (full traces )`) and new analysis: http://pastebin.com/FcLwsV0b, which doesn't tell me much though - on idea where to look at

Comment: hm, the debugger engine DLL does some wired things. Submit it on connect and attach the latest dmp file: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: I see you opened a case: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2752690 also share the real dmp file to Microsoft

Comment: Last time I tried to upload the .dmp, the MS forum was so slow it did not upload. Now I don't have the .dmp file from back then anymore, since I re-installed VS completely new (and it's still not working), but I created the VSFeedback.zip as per the MS staff's description and attached it again.

Comment: does it still happen with the Update 3 or does it fix it? Microsoft also released a stability fix for Update 3: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx. try this update if you still have the issue

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, will give it a try.

Comment: and what happens? Do you still get a crash or not?

Comment: I didn't want to waste much more time with this so I just setup a new desktop as my development machine.